# Eclipse Gradle Spring Boot MVC Build does not recognize jsp's

Tags: eclipse, spring-mvc, gradle, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot MVC.  I have a simple Hello World MVC application that I found on the web.  I am aware of several problems with Spring Boot embedded running MVC.  I believe I have modified my application to handle these problems.  The last issue I am having is running the application as Eclipse "Run as Spring Boot App" feature with jsp's.  If I build my application from the command prompt with Gradle and run the executable war file everything works fine including displaying jsp webpage elements.

```
 >Gradle Build
    ...
    ...
 > cd build\libs
 > java -jar MvcDemo3.war
```

If I run the application in Eclispe as "Run as Spring Boot App", the browser displays the webpage but none of the jsp elements are correct.  It is as if the server side code is not recognizing jsp code.

Here is my build.graddle code,

```
 buildscript {
     ext {
         springBootVersion = '1.4.1.RELEASE'
     }
     repositories {
         mavenCentral()
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-
         plugin:${springBootVersion}")
     }
 }

 apply plugin: 'java'
 apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
 apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
 apply plugin: 'war'


 war {
     baseName = 'MvcDemo3'
     version = 'v001'
 }
 sourceCompatibility = 1.8
 targetCompatibility = 1.8

 repositories {
     mavenCentral()
 }

 configurations {
     providedRuntime
 }

 dependencies {
     compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
     compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper') 
 }
```

Not sure why command line Gradle .war build works but Eclipse does not.  I have read that Eclipse does not come with jsp support.  I tried adding jstl jars to the build but no luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that spring boot mvc using jsp's is not supported using jars.  All I had to do was modify the gradle.build to build a .war instead of a .jar.  I executed the .war and it worked perfectly.  Of course I read the spring boot mvc documentation after I discovered this problem and the specifically point out that you need to create an executable .war instead of a .jar.  For any newbies, you execute the .war in command line using; java -jar MyMvcApplication.war.